# Subtotal with a sumproduct?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subtotal, sumproduct

I have read multiple answers on here and tried to implement how would i do this? Just want to add a subtotal?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E$9:E$500,MOD(ROW(E$9:E$500)+1,2))
```

Comment: Add a subtotal where? To what range? What's the data?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)